# Linking to a page via a button with an href isn't working

Tags: html, css

When I put a button tag on "sign up" it doesn't take me to the page I set up, but when I remove the button tag, it works.

Buttons with `href` won't work. Especially on the "sign up" button. But the other buttons are working. Does anybody know what the problem is?

```css
.button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  /* Green */
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  width: 70px;
  height: 30px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
  /* Safari */
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button1 {
  background-color: #ccd9ff;
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid #555555;
}

.button1:hover {
  background-color: #808080;
  color: white;
}

.button2 {
  background-color: #ccd9ff;
  color: black;
  border: none;
}

.button2:hover {
  background-color: ffcccc;
  color: white;
}

.button3 {
  background-color: #ccd9ff;
  color: black;
  border: none;
}

.button3:hover {
  background-color: #ff99e6;
  color: white;
}

.button4 {
  background-color: #ccd9ff;
  color: black;
  border: none;
}

.button4:hover {
  background-color: #ff9999;
}

.button5 {
  background-color: #ccd9ff;
  color: black;
  border: none;
}

.button5:hover {
  background-color: #ffb399;
  color: white;
}

.button6 {
  background-color: #ccd9ff;
  color: black;
  border: none;
}

.button6:hover {
  background-color: #9999ff;
  color: white;
}

.button7 {
  background-color: #ccd9ff;
  color: black;
  border: none;
}

.button7:hover {
  background-color: #ccccff;
  color: white;
}

.button8 {
  background-color: #ccd9ff;
  color: black;
  border: none;
}

.button8:hover {
  background-color: #ffffcc;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<form id="searchbox" action="">
  <input id="search" type="text" placeholder="Search Anime">
  <button class="button button1" id="submit" type="submit" value="Search">Search</button>
  <FONT face="Comic Sans MS" COLOR="#ff4d4d" SIZE=2>Login</FONT> or
  <A HREF=register.html style="text-decoration:none">
    <button class="button button8" <FONT face="Comic Sans MS" COLOR="#ff4d4d" SIZE=2>Sign Up</FONT><Button>
 </A>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should close the anchor tag and use quotes around the link

```
<a href='register.html' style="text-decoration:none">my link  </a>
```

PS use lowercase for tag eg:  `<a>` and attribute  eg: `href`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<input type="submit" class="button button8" value="Sign Up">
```

Style it via external CSS rather than inline.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that's because HTML doesn't work that way... I advise you to follow some W3C Tutorial.
Start off here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp

Anyway, the main problem I think it's that, in the DOM Tree, you can't have inline elements (such as ) containing block elements (such as )

So with  I'd add an onclick attribute, rather than putting the button inside an

Also, to be sure with HTML, always use this syntax:

Note the lowercase, and the quoting marks!